# Etymology of 目茶目茶

Tags: etymology, ateji

Does anyone know how the kanji for "eye" and "tea" came to be joined to mean "disorderly"? (I am a beginning student and cannot read advanced monolingual dictionaries.) Googling didn't bring up any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kanji spellings for both むちゃ （無茶） and めちゃ （滅茶／目茶） are examples of [ateji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateji) (当{あ}て字{じ}), kanji used only for their phonetic value and **not** for their meanings.

According to dictionaries, [めちゃ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%BB%85%E8%8C%B6-643954) developed as sound shift from [むちゃ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%84%A1%E8%8C%B6-641920).